# MongoDB error: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: php, mongodb, database-connection

I am running into a weird error when trying connect to mongodb. I am running this mongo server on amazon. I have multiple processes accessing the same database and thats when I get the error. It doesn't happen when I run a single process accessing the db. Anyways, this is the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with
>   message 'connecting to
>   mongodb://(username):(password)@(server):(port)/(db) failed: Cannot
>   assign requested address' in /var/www/html/dev/folder/process.php:151

and on line 51:

```
$m = new Mongo('mongodb://(username):(password)@(server):(port)/(db)');
```

any ideas of what this means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error can occur if the server system runs out of ports. That can be caused from a bug in mongodb (1.0.4) or just by the pure number of connections.

Reduce connections and/or switching to persistent connections might help as well.

```
$connection = new Mongo('mongodb://localhost', array('persist' => 
'php'));
```

[Source](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/8603fe2a4cc54aa8)

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to have worked. Weird, I didn't find that discussion when I was researching this issue.

Comment: It's best to search for the phrase of the error but taking the information that changes out (like the server- and username). This often reveals good information if other wrote about the same error. To search for a phrase put it into quotes. Another way is to lookup the phrase in the original source and to read the code what triggers it. That takes more time but is appropriate if an internet search does not reveal anything useful.